# Smooch change language of output of bot

Tags: application-settings, smooch

I am working with Smooth and I would like to know how to change the text of the app. Currently it is in English but I would like to have the text in Dutch. How would I go about that?

cheers

Wouter

Comment: (to be precise the response the app returns is all in English and that should be in Dutch)

Comment: Are you talking about localisation? http://docs.smooch.io/ios/#localization

Comment: yes - but that is only valid for the ios - not for the web...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override all strings in the Smooch web UI by specifying them in the `customText` option of the `Smooch.init` call:

http://docs.smooch.io/javascript/#strings-customization

The whole list of overridable strings is [here](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-js/blob/master/src/js/reducers/ui-reducer.js#L6).

Note that this overrides strings for all of your users, so for now unfortunately you can get all Dutch or all English. We're still working on building proper localization in the widget, e.g. letting you specify a locale to init, and detecting a preferred language via the user agent.

Comment: brilliant! you made my day. definitely +1

I am done here :)